# Merge and overwrite values in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df's containing that I'm hoping to merge and overwrite specific values. Using below, `df1` and `df2` will be merged and I'm hoping to overwrite the values in `Group` for certain rows. Specifically, where `Group` is == `Y`, I want to use the values in `df2`. I've got a way but I don't think it's very efficient.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','E'],    
    'Group' : ['X','X','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X'],            
   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Time' : [1,2,2],        
    'Label' : ['D','B','D'],  
    'Group2' : ['Y1','Y3','Y2'],                                            
    })

df_out = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'outer')
```

out:

```
   Time Label Group Group2
0     1     A     X    NaN
1     1     B     X    NaN
2     1     C     X    NaN
3     1     D     Y     Y1
4     2     A     X    NaN
5     2     B     Y     Y3
6     2     C     X    NaN
7     2     D     Y     Y2
8     2     E     X    NaN
```

I could then copy `Group2` to `Group` excluding the NaN values and then drop `Group2` but is there a more efficient method

Comment: Do you want yo update values of `df1['Group']` from `df2['Group2']` on `Time` and `Label` columns?

Comment: Yep. I'll check out update.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to update `df1['Group']` with `df2['Group2']` values:

```
df1["Group"].update(df1.merge(df2, on=["Time", "Label"], how="outer")["Group2"])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   Time Label Group
0     1     A     X
1     1     B     X
2     1     C     X
3     1     D    Y1
4     2     A     X
5     2     B    Y3
6     2     C     X
7     2     D    Y2
8     2     E     X
```

Comment: yep this is what I want